# No module named 'psycopg2.extensions' despite having 'psycopg2-binary'

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I am trying to develop a Django project leveraging `psycopg2` but when i deploy in a Docker container on `python:3.7.4-slim` I was running into the 'no pg_config' issue, so I determined the best way to proceed after some digging is to go with `psycopg2-binary` since since that seems to be the recommended way to go forward.

Only problem now is that when I try to run the command `python manage.py <...>` from local I'm getting the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2.extensions'`

I'm not sure how to proceed, since `psycopg2` works fine locally but we are going to end up containerizing this resource and having it sit in a k8s cluster so I was fairly certain the binary library was the right way to go.  Has anyone figured out a solution to pull in `psycopg2.extensions` without sacrificing the integrity of using the binary distribution?

My main gripe is i don't understand why `psycopg2` would come with this `extensions` module, while `binary` would not, and at this point it feels like the workaround is to brute-force stash `extensions` somewhere locally in my repository just have it called that way, although I feel like there has got to be a more intuitive workaround.

It's also entirely possible I misunderstood the use of `psycopg2` vs binary, and I should be using the former when I deploy and I'm not aware of what dependencies it requires in a linux environment?

Happy to provide more context as-needed.

Thanks!

Comment: I've typically just added the path to `pg_config` to `$PATH` before doing `pip install psycopg2`. Or make a symlink: `ln -s /var/lib/pgsql/10.1/bin/pg_config /usr/sbin/pg_config`. What distro are you using under the hood?

Comment: @FlipperPA I am using the `python:3.7.4-slim` docker image- I believe underlying Linux distro is debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that I was overcomplicating the problem by 'solutioning'-- I falsely thought the best approach was to use `psycopg2-binary` because I couldn't figure out the correct dependencies.  After a little bit of digging I was able to figure out that `psyocopg2` will work with the `python:3.7.4-slim` image (among others - I'm sure this cascades to other distros as well) by running the following prior to `pip install`:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc
```

It appears that this is all that's needed to use `psycopg2` as opposed to the binary.